# Are there other languages, besides Old Slavonic, with adjectives ending with pronoun?

Tags: etymology

Are there other languages, besides Old Slavonic, with adjectives ending with pronoun, e.g.

добрый /dobryj/ he who is good;
доброе /dobrojo/ it which is good;
добрую /dobruju/ she who is good;
добрыя /dobryja/ they who are good

Comment: https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/30919/are-there-other-languages-besides-old-slavonic-where-pronouns-in-a-nominative

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lithuanian, which is related to but not descended from Slavic languages, is also supposed to have "pronominal adjectives", according to this web page: [The Historical Grammar of Lithuanian language](http://babaev.tripod.com/archive/grammar11.html#4)

That page indicates that pronominal adjectives don't exist in Indo-European languages outside of Baltic and Slavic.

It's not the same thing, but a somewhat similar phenomenon that does exist outside of Baltic or Slavic languages is the use of a definite article with an attributive adjective. This shows up in Greek, and I think I remember reading about it occurring in some Germanic language (possibly a type of Yiddish). Outside of Indo-European, you can find definite articles affixed or cliticized to adjectives in Semitic languages such as Arabic and Hebrew. Obviously, this is different in that the noun also is marked with the definite marker, and the definite marker is not a pronoun. However, definite articles and pronouns often do have some similarities. Another difference is that all of the languages that I mentioned in this paragraph put the definite marker at the start, not at the end of the adjective.

[Slovenian](http://www.ung.si/~rzaucer/papers/MarusicZaucer-2007-Adjectival-definite-article-in-Slo.pdf) uses "ta", which is apparently the same in form as a demonstrative pronoun, as something often called an "adjectival definite article". Unlike the examples in the previous paragraph, it apparently can't be used with a bare noun. Slovenian is a Slavic language.

In Germanic languages generally, there is the phenomenon of attributive adjectives having "strong" or "weak" inflection depending on the presence of a definite article. It seems that the "strong" inflectional suffixes are somehow related to demonstrative pronouns. "[The adjective in Germanic and Romance Development, Differences and Similarities](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/61af/0d95fd09b3e47402c2c3a479f329dcfa5d2b.pdf)", by Freek Van de Velde, Petra Sleeman & Harry Perridon, says "The origin of the [Germanic] strong inflection [...] is the endings in the demonstratives, which rubbed off onto other elements, through an intermediate group of semi-pronouns (Kluge 1913: 209; Prokosch 1939:
261; McFadden 2009)" (p. 3).

Answer (score 0):

These adjectives do not end in a pronoun, they end in a case ending. These are nominative case endings, which just so happen to be identical to certain nominative pronouns.

Comment: I don’t think it’s a coincidence, though ... if I remember correctly, those case endings are in fact supposed to have developed from suffixed pronouns.

Comment: The [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Old_Church_Slavonic_grammar#Adjectives), as well as the following web page corroborates what I remember reading: http://babaev.tripod.com/archive/grammar32.html

Comment: @sumelic, would you say the same thing about for example Latin?

Comment: Can you explain a bit more why Latin could be considered comparable? Latin adjectives don't have "short" and "long" forms like Slavonic adjectives.

Comment: @sumelic well Latin adjectives and OCS adjectives are typologically very similar, aren't they. Both end in something which is homonymous to whatever the 3rd person pronoun ends in. No need to posit that it *is* the pronoun imho.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. I think of the Latin third-person pronoun as being "is, ea, id" in the nominative singular. But Latin neuter adjectives typically have a nominative singular form that ends in "um", less commonly "e" or "s" (or "x"), very rarely something else like "r". "Id" is not a typical neuter nominative singular adjective ending at all. (This Latin SE questions mentions some other words with the -d ending, and there only seem to be a handful: https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/2536/why-is-d-used-instead-of-m-for-most-neuter-pronouns)

Comment: @Wilson: I don't know much OCS. But in Russian, adjectives normally have a 'short' form, used in certain restricted circumstances, and a longer form used generally. The short form has recognisable endings partly resembling nominal case forms. The long form has that, and in many cases a further ending, which sometimes more or less reduplicates the short ending - as in the OCS examples above. The long form certainly looks like something suffixed onto the basic declined adjective. I know nothing like it in Latin, or any Western European language.

Comment: @ColinFine you are right that it "looks like something suffixed" to the end of a basic adjective. But I don't consider this good enough reason to posit that this **is a pronoun**. Can you explain why you consider that the case?

Comment: @Wilson: I didn't say it was a pronoun, Artur Makarov did. I was disagreeing with your statement that the Latin and Slavonic adjectives were "typologically similar".